# How to render trelliscope within shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, render

It seems that trelliscope is not able to use within shiny even though renderTrelliscope function is included. Could any of you help me to confirm this ?

Although these link seems to help:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/trelliscopejs/versions/0.1.18/topics/Trelliscope-shiny

An issue but couldnt help me
https://github.com/hafen/trelliscopejs/issues/37

```
library(shiny)
install.packages("gapminder")
library(gapminder)
devtools::install_github("hafen/trelliscopejs")
library(trelliscopejs)
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello trelliscope in Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  fluidPage(

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Histogram ----
      trelliscopeOutput("plot", width = "100%", height = "400px")

    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderTrelliscope(
    qplot(year, lifeExp, data = gapminder) +
      xlim(1948, 2011) + ylim(10, 95) + theme_bw() +
      facet_trelliscope(~ country + continent,
                        nrow = 2, ncol = 7, width = 300, as_plotly = TRUE)

    )
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can we render facet_trelliscope within shiny ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new trelliscope R package and there is documentation on how to embed in Shiny apps: https://trelliscope.org/trelliscope/articles/embed.html.